# jQuery Selector not detecting modified element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'm coding a kind of ordered photo managing panel in which I use flexbox and the order attribute. The order attribute is loaded from the database and all elements are showing correctly. I've also done a function to change that order. This consists in two arrows which moves the element right or left, modifies it's order attribute and it modifies it in the database using ajax.

My problem is that after I modify the order attribute with jQuery that element no longer can be accessed with selectors, so when I move the element right and after that I move it left it doesn't work.

With the developer console I've tried to exec the script instruction by instruction and the problem is that when I select an element with:

```
var element = $('.thumb[style="order: 3"]');
```

It returns the correct element, but if after that I modify it using:

```
element.css('order',4);
```

When I use the selector again it doesn't return anything.

```
$('.thumb[style="order: 4"]');
```

returns

```
[]
```

But in the element inspector of Chrome and Firefox I see that the element has changed it's order.

I've made a fiddle to show this issue. I've tried to search but didn't find anything. Any help is appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/fskxw2wp/

Comment: Why don't you give your elements an id ?

Comment: Why did you create your example on a third party site? Is something wrong with [snippets](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? The example isn't very helpful anyway: You don't have an element with class="thumb" in it.

Comment: I didn't know the existence of snippets. In the fiddle if you look carefully the thumb elements are added by javascript, there are 5 elements with "thumb" class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because when you add the attribute using `.css`, it adds a semicolon after the value:

```
<div class="thumb" style="order: 1;">2</div>
```

So your selector is now wrong (as it doesn't contain the semi-colon)

I would either add this to your initial [load and selector (updated fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/fskxw2wp/1/) or change to use a data-attribute instead and do a filter on that

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem. The mising semicolon when adding the content. Corrected and working like a charm. Many thanks!

Comment: You could actually just change your selector to be a bit more forgiving (in case other styles are added): `$('.thumb[style*="order: 4;"]');` should select where the style attribute has `order: 4;` anywhere (I would keep the semicolon incase you had `order: 40`) - https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/